# Calculations using aliases (from a subquery to the same table) mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database that stores player kills in CS:GO, I am trying to write a query that can show each player's KD.

I've written a query that will show each player's kills and deaths using aliases.

```
SELECT
    `Name`,
    `SteamID` as PlayerID,
    count(`EventType`) as kills,
    (SELECT count(`EventType`)
     FROM `logdata`
     WHERE (`EventVariable` = PlayerID AND `EventType` = 'killed')
     GROUP BY `EventVariable`
     ORDER BY `count(``EventType``)` DESC) as deaths
FROM `logdata`
WHERE `EventType` = 'killed'
GROUP BY `EventType`, `Name`
ORDER BY kills DESC
```

*(results limited to just bots, I didn't want to openly advertise my friends SteamIDs)*
[image: kills and deaths totals for each player]

To work out KD I just need to divide `kills / deaths` but you can't do that with aliases, I read that I should be able to wrap the alias e.g. `(SELECT kills) / (SELECT deaths) as KD` but that doesn't work.

The table looks like this: *(Limited to bots again)*
[image: MySQL table contents]

I am currently working out KD in PHP using the result of my query but that isn't a great way of doing it. (I am unable to query who has the highest KD for example)

So, my question is, how would I go about calculating the KD if I am unable to make calculations using alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might just write your query using two completely separate subqueries which compute the kills and deaths counts:

```
SELECT
    n.Name,
    COALESCE(t1.kill_cnt, 0) AS kills,
    COALESCE(t2.death_cnt, 0) AS deaths,
    CASE WHEN t2.death_cnt > 0
         THEN CAST(t1.kill_cnt / t2.death_cnt AS CHAR(50))
         ELSE 'NA' END AS ratio
FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM logdata ) n
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS kill_cnt
    FROM logdata
    WHERE EventType = 'killed'
    GROUP BY Name
) t1
ON
    n.Name = t1.Name
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT EventVariable AS Name, COUNT(*) AS death_cnt
    FROM logdata
    WHERE EventType = 'killed'
    GROUP BY Name
) t2
ON
    n.Name = t2.Name
```

Note that the subquery above which I have aliased as `n` is just intended to generate a complete list of all users in your database.  Ideally, there should be a dedicated user table somewhere.  If not, and you don't like my approach, then you will have to come up with some other way to obtain a list of all users.

Comment: I get "Unknown column 't1.death_cnt' in 'field list'" with that query. My colleague suggested using a separate dedicated user table but I did not see how this could work when querying a specific range. I.E. if I wanted only kills with the 'awp'

Comment: I see t2 is the name of the joined table - death_cnt should be t2.death_cnt?, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! ...I am not a MySQL ninja (yet)

Comment: @RobinWright It should be `t2.death_cnt`.  Sorry, this was a typo, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim for pointing me in the right direction and providing a query. I have made some changes to get the result I want and I wanted to post the final result.

```
SELECT
    n.SteamID,
    COALESCE(t1.kill_cnt, 0) AS kills,
    COALESCE(t2.death_cnt, 0) AS deaths,
    CASE WHEN t2.death_cnt > 0 THEN CAST(t1.kill_cnt / t2.death_cnt AS CHAR(50))
         WHEN t1.kill_cnt = 0 THEN '0'
         ELSE 'Infinite' END AS ratio
FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT SteamID FROM logdata ) n
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SteamID, COUNT(*) AS kill_cnt
    FROM logdata
    WHERE EventType = 'killed'
    GROUP BY SteamID
) t1
ON
    n.SteamID = t1.SteamID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT EventVariable AS SteamID, COUNT(*) AS death_cnt
    FROM logdata
    WHERE EventType = 'killed'
    GROUP BY EventVariable
) t2
ON
    n.SteamID = t2.SteamID  
WHERE t1.kill_cnt > 0 or t2.death_cnt > 0
ORDER BY `ratio` DESC
```

I attempted to get KD 0 to show as such but that is not all that important at the end of the day, NULL is easy to work with.

[image: result]